# NGINX 2 domains on the same IP, want to redirect both to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I have 2 domains running on my server, NGINX just proxies them to node apps. I have a certificate for one, but for the other I'm just using cloudflare to provide HTTPS. I want to ensure that when users visit either domain, they always get redirected to the HTTPS version of the domain, without a www. This is my current configuration, uncommenting the block for the domain2 configuration file seems to break both sites :(

**domain1 config file:**

```
upstream domain1.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {

    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    #listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain1.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com.log;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/client/public;

    include /etc/nginx/global/cloudflare-allow.conf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain1.key;

    if ($bad_referer) {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_pass http://domain1.com;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|webp)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
        expires 1h;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
    }

 }

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;

}
```

**domain2 config file:**

```
upstream domain2.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    keepalive 8;
}

#server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;
#    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
#}

server {
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain2.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.com.log;

    root /var/www/domain2.com;

    include /etc/nginx/global/cloudflare-allow.conf;

    if ($bad_referer) {
        return 444;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_pass http://domain2.com;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|webp)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
        expires 1h;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SSL is done through CloudFlare's Flexible SSL mode, communication to the origin is HTTP traffic over port 80.

In order to detect whether this traffic is HTTPS you can't use the HTTPS environment variable, you must then check if the X-Forwarded-Proto header is set to HTTPS instead.

You can do this in Nginx as follows:

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
```

The easier way to do this is to simply set an ["Always use HTTPS" Page Rule in CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-).